# Get a list of duplicate entries in List based on 2 fields using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am using the following Linq to determine if there are any invalid entries in my list during some custom validation - I want to know if any Persons have been assigned the same Number based on the Company they work for which works fine:

```
var duplicates = Persons.GroupBy(x => 
                new { x.Number, x.CompanyId}, (key) => new { key.Number, key.CompanyId })
                .Where(y => y.Count() > 1);
```

For a simple class of Person:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

So build some test data:

```
List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
// add people (users would do this!)
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 1", Number = 1, CompanyId = 1 }); // invalid
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 2", Number = 2, CompanyId = 1 });
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 3", Number = 3, CompanyId = 1 });
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 4", Number = 1, CompanyId = 1 }); // invalid
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 5", Number = 2, CompanyId = 2 }); // invalid
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 6", Number = 2, CompanyId = 2 }); // invalid
```

Check if any duplicates and handle:

```
var duplicates = Persons.GroupBy(x => 
                new { x.Number, x.CompanyId}, (key) => new { key.Number, key.CompanyId })
                .Where(y => y.Count() > 1);

if (duplicates.Any())
{
    // build a string
}
```

What I want to do is to get a list of the invalid entries and inform the user.  So in the above case, I would want to output the following text:

- Person 1 and Person 4 have been assigned the same Number #1 for Company #1.
- Person 5 and Person 6 have been assigned the same Number #2 for Company #2.

Comment: Have you though of something like... Persons.Where(p => (p.Number == p.CompanyId)) then group the result accordingly

Comment: Number == Company?  This won't work as Number has no relation to Company.  Each Company has their own Numbering system.  Number and Company must for the key in the GroupBy.

Comment: You should clarify why the Person Number or CompanyId are invalid, is it because of the duplicate Number or what!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your group by to return the name as the selection and group by your key.  String.Join will then merge the list

```
var duplicates = Persons
    .GroupBy(key => new { key.Number, key.CompanyId }, a=>a.Name)
    .Where(y => y.Count() > 1);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
{
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} have been assigned the same Number {1} for Company #{2}",
                                String.Join(" and ", duplicate), duplicate.Key.Number,
                                duplicate.Key.CompanyId));
}
var message = sb.ToString();
```

Now check if message is empty to know if you have duplicates instead of your Any() statement.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Works nicely.  Still digesting it.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to write grouping LINQ queries correctly using the query syntax rather than the fluent syntax. Here's a query that'll get you the strings you want:

```
from p in Persons   
group p by new { p.Number, p.CompanyId } into g
where g.Count () > 1
select string.Format(
    "{0} have been assigned the same number #{1} for company {2}",
    string.Join(" and ", g.Select (x => x.Name)),
    g.Key.Number,
    g.Key.CompanyId);
```

Note that that query won't work as a LINQ-to-SQL/Entities query, it'll only work against in memory data.

Comment: Thanks for the info Steve.  I'm using in memory checks luckly as the data has been loaded to my EF ObjectStateManager where I am essentially doing this on.  Still taking me some getting used to